# facebook graph api insights can't select a date range?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Facebook Graph API to access the app insights for an app that I have. I'm using the graph explorer with the GET as: app-id/app_insights/facebook_login_total_users

It returns the following json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": "2014-08-15T07:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "62"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-08-16T07:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "57"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-08-17T07:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "98"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-08-18T07:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "18"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-08-19T07:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "57"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2014-08-20T07:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "51"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the app has been living for longer than that, but I can't seem to find out how to get all the date ranges, or even the total over the lifetime of the app. I'd like to be able to select different date ranges through the Graph API with this endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the start point using `since` and the end point using `until` within your query by using the [app_insight modifiers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/app_insights#modifiers). For example, to get the date ranges starting from 2013-10-15, you can simply use a query like:

```
app-id/app_insights/facebook_login_total_users?since=2013-10-15
```

This will give you details for all the dates since 2013-10-15.